# Showing a trajectory is attracted to an invariant line

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, chaos-theory, nonlinear-analysis

Given the system $x' = ax^c - \phi x$, $y' = by^c - \phi y$,  $\phi = ax^c + b^c$

Part a was just showing that the derivative is $0$, which I was able to just fine.

The second part of the question says:
Show that all trajectories starting in the positive quadrant are attracted
to the invariant line $x + y =1$ found in part (a). Thus, the analysis of
the system’s longterm dynamics boils down to figuring out how
trajectories flow along this invariant line

I have no idea how to even start so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are there constraints on $a,b,c$?

Comment: What does the superscript $c$ mean?